# How do I bypass asking end-user for username while adding a blog post using a form and automatically display logged in user as post author?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a simple blog which has a model Post. I am trying to create a form for adding blog posts (or adding comments to posts for that matter) so that end users don't have to fill out a form box asking the end user for a username. I would like to be able to just ask for a title and body text for a blog post, and when hit post, it will be posted as the authenticated user.

I tried not including 'user' field in fields in forms, but it seems to be mandatory. Maybe I need to just make it hidden somehow using widgets? In templates, I could maybe write the following:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   <p>Posting as {{request.user}}</p>
{% else %}
   <p><a href={% url 'register' %}Please register to add a blog post</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Though I am not sure, I think it would make more sense to have logic in my views.py file.

Here's my 'blog.models' file:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug            = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    text            = models.TextField()
    published_date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # pip install Pillow
    image           = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                                        upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/',)


    def summary(self):
        """Return a summary for very long posts to
        get a glimpse from admin panel"""
        return self.text[:100]

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        """Assigns a number to the end of a given slug field to prevent
        duplicated slug error. if title of a post is 'ayancik', and another
        user creates another post with the same title, second posts' slug
        is assigned a value: 'ayancik-2'"""
        slug = slugify(self.title)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Post.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Automatically assign slug to objects
        by overriding save method"""
        self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.published_date.strftime('%b %e, %Y')

    def __str__(self):
        """String representation"""
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # what does kwargs={'slug':self.slug} really achieve here?
        # where would we use 'key-value' pair?
        """Returns the url to access a detailed post"""
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-published_date',]


class Comment(models.Model):
    post                = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='comments')
    user                = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text                = models.TextField()
    created_date        = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve_comment(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

'blog.forms' file:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['user', 'title', 'text', 'image']

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('user', 'text',)
```

and 'blog.views' file:

```
@login_required
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if post_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save(request)
            post.save()
        else:
            print(post_form.errors)
    else:
            # when not POST request, display the empty form
            # meaning -> if request.method=='GET':
            post_form = PostForm()

    context = {
        'post_form': post_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/addpost.html', context)

def add_comment_to_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', slug=slug)

    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    template_name = 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html'
    return render(request, template_name , {'form': form })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omit the user in the `PostForm`:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        # no user
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'image']
```

or we can display all fields except `'user'` like:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('user', )
```

and then you add the user to the instance in your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if post_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('some_view')
    else:
        post_form = PostForm()

    context = {
        'post_form': post_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/addpost.html', context)
```

The `commit=False` thus prevents the from from saving the `Post` object to the database.

Since you want to upload an `image`, you should pass [**`request.FILES`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the `PostForm` as well, otherwise you will not process uploaded files. You furthermore need to specify that you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'create_post' %}">
    ...
</form>
```

It is better to use a [**`redirect`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/) in case of a successful POST request, since this is the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). By rendering a new form, if the user refreshes the page, he/she would create a second post, which is probably not what you want.